# Vaadin with JMS in Glassfish 4.1 exception

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms, vaadin, vaadin7

Im currently trying to integrate Vaadin with JMS in an war app in glassfish 4.1. I followed the example [here](https://github.com/mstahv/java-ee-jms-vaadin-chat) but it keeps throwing an exception :
**javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: [C4306]: This method may not be called in a Java EE web or EJB container.**

The full stack:

```
    StandardWrapperValve[UtisServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet UtisServlet threw exception
javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: [C4306]: This method may not be called in a Java EE web or EJB container
    at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.JMSConsumerImpl.setMessageListener(JMSConsumerImpl.java:261)
    at org.vaadin.msghub.AbstractMessageHub.startListening(AbstractMessageHub.java:68)
    at com.utis.personneltracking.UtisUI.init(UtisUI.java:94)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:646)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:214)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1408)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:350)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is anyone familiar with this issue? or anyone managed to integrate Vaadin with JMS?

Im running on Vaadin 7.4.1

Answer (score 2):

You should run a server instance of your JMS **OUTSIDE** of the servlet container.

This JMS server instance can then be used as the target point to publish & subscribe messages.

Comment: im using glassfish as the application server and i have 2 separate war applications one of which vaadin. can you be a bit more specific on how to run the JMS instance outside the servlet container?

Comment: i run this example project : https://github.com/mstahv/java-ee-jms-vaadin-chat  with the same result

Comment: As the error shows, this way of working is not supported in EE or EJB environments. It might perhaps work depending of your container, but it's not intended that way. Definitively use a container-external instance of the JMS broker.

Comment: thank for the reply. do u have any suggestion as which JMS brokers would fix this issue. Im stuck with Glassfish server and i cant change the server environment. eventually id have to integrate an external container if my understanding is correct. One more detail, previously i did a successful test on 2 different war applications based on EJBs and ManagedBeans and JMS worked as expected. however with Vaadin it fails and if i add a @MessageDriven bean inside vaadin application it somehow runs outside the vaadin context and cant access UI or VaadinServlet

Comment: Hmmm... we seldom use EJB containers, so I can't answer that.
When we are in a pure Java environment we use JORAM (http://joram.ow2.org/), when need interoperability with other languages, then we go for ActiveMQ (http://activemq.apache.org/).

Comment: i integrated Apache ActiveMQ in glassfish but the same error persist. Ive run out of ideas. have u ever make vaadin work with some sort of JMS or RPC calls from outside application? if yes could you direct me to some sample code